# can i make if's shorter?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is it possible to make if statements shorter? For example:

```
if (intno == 0 || intno == 4 || intno == 7)
```

could be something like:

```
if (intno == 0 || 4 || 7)
```

That'll bring up an error, but is there anything like that?

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before...

Comment: that should be pretty obvious...... but anyway, `Int int = 0;` would be what it meant

Comment: You should be knowing `int` is a keyword.

Comment: Try writing `Int int = 0` you will surely get a compilation error.

Comment: i it was just an example >.>

Comment: switch case could be an alternate

Comment: i did think of switch but it's not usable for me

Comment: `Arrays.asList(0,4,7).contains(intno)` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

For integer types and enums, you could use a switch statement instead:

```
switch(intno) {
     case 0:
     case 4:
     case 7:
          //code here
          break;
}
```

This also works for Strings in Java 7+

Answer (score 1):

The following has already been suggested in the comments:

```
Arrays.asList(0, 4, 7).contains(intno)
```

It is correct and shorter, but it is slower.

Note that this code is performing a lot of operations behind the scenes:

- Convert the `0`, `4` and `7` `int`s to `Integer`s.
- Create an array containing those objects
- Create a `List` containing that array
- Convert `intno` to `Integer`
- Perform a linear search over the list, calling `equals` on every object

This is *way* slower than just three checks. Of course, if you're executing that code once every time the user clicks a button, it doesn't matter. If you call it a hundred times per second, it might.

In my opinion, however, using this can be clearer than using a long if, especially if instead of 3 there are 15 valid conditions. If instead of using magic numbers you even store the returned list, you might get some clarity points:

```
private static final List<Integer> VALID_NUMBERS = Arrays.asList(0, 4, 7);

// ...

if (VALID_NUMBERS.contains(intno)) {
    // Code here
}
```

It *is* shorter and arguably clearer. It **is** slower, so be careful with these constructs, bon't just use it every time you can.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate truth mapping as

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
map.add(0);
map.add(4);
map.add(7);
```

and then

```
if(map.contains(intValue){
}
```

Comment: Seriously? I would nearly not even go for a `Set`, but a whole `Map`? And then, your map doesn't contain values for the other ints and will return `null` instead of true or false.

Comment: I would use a `Set` here. But it is also much slower than the original `if`.

Comment: How are 5 lines shorter than 1?

Comment: i didn't include it but within the if statement i change the `intno` to another number, how would i do this with maps?

Comment: @Alex it is shorter when it gets expanded further consider 10 such ORing

Comment: There is a missing bracket on the if and map doesn't have a  `contains` method.